# android kmm не собирается с ошибкой

Tags: android, ios

Есть проект android kmm, писал его не я, у себя его нужно настроить, связи с разработчиками нету.

Всплывает такая ошибка:

> Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "chmod"

Запускаю на эмуляторе.
Как её поправить?

**По какой-то ерунде забанили на основном стэке. Приложу все доступные параметры сюда:**

> Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2 Build
> #AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639, built on May 12, 2023 Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694 x86_64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o. macOS 12.6.7 GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old
> Generation Memory: 2048M Cores: 8 Metal Rendering is ON Registry:
> external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
> ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
> gradle.version.catalogs.dynamic.support=true
>
> Non-Bundled Plugins:
> name.kropp.intellij.makefile (222.4459.16)
> com.thoughtworks.gauge (222.4459.16)
> com.mobidevelop.robovm.intellij (2.3.19)
> com.jetbrains.kmm (0.6.0(222)-13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге у меня всё получилось. Изучите эту тему -> [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1550115/android-kmm-При-сборке-kmm-проекта-получаю-ошибку-code65](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1550115/android-kmm-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5-kmm-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-code65)

Проблемы решил при помощи: applyDefaultHierarchyTemplate() & изучите ссылки:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-60734
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-62599/KMM-KotlinSourceSet-with-name-iosMain-not-found-error