# Android KMM: При сборке KMM проекта получаю ошибку: ...code:65

Tags: android, ios, kotlin-multiplatform

Есть проект, написанный не мной. KMM. Пытаюсь его запустить и получаю ошибку:
Built iOS application: failed with code 65 ...
Нигде не могу найти причину, что это за код ошибки "65" и как её поправить. Кто-нибудь знает? Как поправить?

[image: ошибка "65"]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблемы решил при помощи:
applyDefaultHierarchyTemplate()
Тем, кто столкнётся с подобной проблемой: читайте об этом методе. Я добавил его в gradle и всё собралось успешно. Это я говорю про Android часть. iOS часть Так и не собралась.

Comment: iOS часть собралась в xCode

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-60734

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-62599/KMM-KotlinSourceSet-with-name-iosMain-not-found-error